# Java 8 DateTimeFormatter parsing for optional fractional seconds of varying significance

Tags: java, java-time, datetime-parsing

My [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (as a [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) unit test):

```
public class MyDateTimeFormatterTest {

    private static final String BASE_PATTERN = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER =
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(BASE_PATTERN + "[.SSSSSSSSS]");
    private static final LocalDateTime TEST_INPUT =
            LocalDateTime.of(2015, 5, 4, 12, 34, 56, 123456789);

    @DataProvider(name = "test-cases")
    public Iterator<Object[]> getTestCases() {
        return Arrays.asList(testFor("", ChronoUnit.SECONDS),
                testFor(".SSS", ChronoUnit.MILLIS),
                testFor(".SSSSSS", ChronoUnit.MICROS),
                testFor(".SSSSSSSSS", ChronoUnit.NANOS)).iterator();
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "test-cases")
    public void testWithDefaultResolution(String input, LocalDateTime output) {
        assertThat(FORMATTER.parse(input, LocalDateTime::from), equalTo(output));
    }

    private Object[] testFor(String patternSuffix, TemporalUnit truncatedTo) {
        return new Object[] { DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(BASE_PATTERN + patternSuffix)
                .format(TEST_INPUT), TEST_INPUT.truncatedTo(truncatedTo) };
    }
}
```

I am trying to test the parsing of a date-time `String` with **optional fractional seconds of varying significance** using [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). The relevant part of the Javadoc reads:

> **Fraction**: Outputs the nano-of-second field as a fraction-of-second. The nano-of-second value has nine digits, thus the count of pattern letters is from 1 to 9. If it is less than 9, then the nano-of-second value is truncated, with only the most significant digits being output.

Based on my limited understanding, I used `[...]` to mark the fractional seconds as optional, and since I'm interested in varying significance, I thought I should stick to `SSSSSSSSS`.

However, the unit test fails at parsing *up to* milliseconds and microseconds, i.e. the second and third cases. Changing the `ResolverStyle` to [`LENIENT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#LENIENT) does not help here as it fails at the parsing stage, not the resolution.

May I know which approaches should I consider to resolve my problem? Should I be using [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) to optionally specify each fractional digit (9 times), or is there a 'smarter' way with my pattern?

**edit** I found my own answer in the end... will still leave this as unanswered for a day and see if there are other approaches or not.

Comment: Did you also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103167/jsr-310-parsing-seconds-fraction-with-variable-length ? Looks like your answer is essentially the same

Comment: @araqnid thanks for pointing that out... I've updated my own answer below to drop `parseLenient()` too, for future references...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Oh cool, another 15 minutes of troubleshooting yielded this:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = 
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern(BASE_PATTERN) // .parseLenient()
        .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true).toFormatter();
```

**edit** `parseLenient()` is [optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30107522/2754160).

Answer (score 3):

### You were close to the solution

[Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30090987/10819573) is definitely an elegant way to solve this problem. However, what you attempted first was also close to the solution. You just had to specify the remaining numbers of fractional parts too while specifying the optional pattern.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.[SSSSSSSSS][SSSSSSSS][SSSSSSS][SSSSSS][SSSSS][SSSS][SSS][SS][S]]",
                Locale.ENGLISH);

        // Test
        Stream.of(
                "2015-05-04 12:34:56.123456789",
                "2015-05-04 12:34:56.123456",
                "2015-05-04 12:34:56.123",
                "2015-05-04 12:34:56"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(s, formatter)));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2015-05-04T12:34:56.123456789
2015-05-04T12:34:56.123456
2015-05-04T12:34:56.123
2015-05-04T12:34:56
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below pattern and it helped me parse the dates without milliseconds and with milliseconds(up to 3 decimal places)

```java
final static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.*][.SSS][.SS][.S]X");
```

e.g.
2023-10-25T10:22:28.280Z
2023-10-25T10:22:28.28Z
2023-10-25T10:22:28.2Z
2023-10-25T10:22:28Z