# Groovy: DateTime comparison of JSON response to JDBC Results

Tags: json, date, groovy

I need to validate the date & timestamp being displayed in a json response to results from jdbc connection to the database. The date & timestamps are taken from the database, manipulated and displayed in UTC format in the JSON response. How can I establish this validation using groovy?

**Dates:**

```
   JSON - formats:
       1999-12-31T05:00:00.000Z
       2016-09-20T04:00:00.000Z
```

Is this the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern to be used -`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`?
The time section of this date will either always be `05:00:00.000Z` or `04:00:00.000Z` regardless of what is in the db.

```
   JDBC - formats:
        1999-12-31 00:00:00
        2016-09-20 09:23:53.139537
        2016-09-20 09:27:13.96773
```

**Timestamps:**

```
   JSON - formats:
        2016-09-20 09:23:53.139537
        2016-09-20 09:27:13.96773
        2016-09-19 09:49:20.0
```

Is this the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern to be used - `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS"`? How to deal with the missing trailing zeroes (`'0'`)?

```
   JDBC - formats:
        2016-09-20 09:23:53.139537
        2016-09-20 09:27:13.96773
        2016-09-19 09:49:20
```

How to deal with the missing trailing zeroes (`'0'`)?

How can I go about with this solution? Any guidance will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what validation you are trying to establish? Do you only want to compare thses dates or anything else?

Comment: @AbhinandanSatpute Yes, I would like to use `assert` on them to compare and validate that the dates represented in the `JSON` response are in fact the same dates from the database but in the correct format for `UTC`. UTC formats can be seen in the `JSON - formats` above.

Comment: Java 8? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090710/java-8-datetimeformatter-parsing-for-optional-fractional-seconds-of-varying-sign

Comment: @tim_yates Will try in Groovy... this could help. Thanks!